# How to get X509Chain in CE/WM - CF .net 3.5

Tags: ssl, certificate, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

This is how it would look on full .net

```
X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();
ch.Build(c);
Debug.WriteLine("Chain Information..");
...
```

The reason i ask this is because i am not able to post data to a secure https website using chained cert from compact framework windows mobile app.

There are many suggestions out there to do override ICertificatePolicy and return true for the cert during HttpWebRequest calls...it is not acceptable sol from security stand point.

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
 //accept all certs.
   return true; 
}
```

My soln was to go through the chain and validate each by comparing thumbprint of each cert in the chain to thumbprints from the device certs.

This is simply what i want to do in CF - and its not working if the cert has chain or uses some kinda of encryption that is not implemented on device.

```
  string data = "hello";
  Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.example.com/");
  HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  request.ContentLength = data.Length;

 using (var stream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) {
                stream.Write(data);
                stream.Flush();
            }
```

But this fails on GetRequestStream() because of ssl validation issue.